# Open source Tool for creating reports of DB structure for SQL Server 2008

Tags: open-source, reporting, sql-server

Any recommendation for open source tool (or evaluation functional software) witch I could generate a report (Excel or Word) of all my tables and fields of a SQL server 2008 Database ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) from [Python](http://www.python.org)/[Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Pandas can use SQL Alchemy to perform just about any [SQL Query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/io.html#sql-queries) into a data table and these can then be written out to excel.

All of the above software is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Licenced to include commercial use *PSF or MIT licence*
- Widely Used
- Actively maintained and developed
- Cross Platform

Answer (score 0):

TOAD Free for Sql Server (formerly from Quest software, now owned by DELL) has schema reports as well as data reports.
They have products for the most common databases with their respective free version , limited but completely usable for the purpose you need it.